# Creating a component library using react native

Tags: react-native

I am using git repos as my UI component libraries in react native for my `react-native init` app.When i am building the whole application with my react-native app and its components libraries i have to modify each UI component commit it and then have to `yarn-upgrade` to view the changes in my final application in dev environment.Is there a way to do this nicely without making the application hard to code and with a same kind of setup where we have several repos for several modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you develop the libraries also, so you need to use `npm link` or [`yarn link`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/)

> For development, a package can be linked into another project. This is often useful to test out new features or when trying to debug an issue in a package that manifests itself in another project.